SharePoint Run Flow Button Visibility
I am trying to show a run flow button in a SharePoint column where:

The Office column is equal to London or Manchester (single choice column)
The employee ID column is not blank (number column)
The buddy column is not blank (single person column)

I have gotten the office field working but I cannot figure out what the not blank logic would be.
Can you please offer any advice?

In my test, toString() function to check null or empty value
Try the following and see it works for you (update the column name and Power Automate Guid)
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "display": "=if(([$City]=='London' || [$City]=='Manchester') && toString([$EmployeeID])!='' && toString([$BuddyPerson])!='', 'block', 'none')"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "button",
      "txtContent": "Run Workflow",
      "customRowAction": {
        "action": "executeFlow",
        "actionParams": "{\"id\":\"2cc9148a-744d-413c-9e3d-6849a6f00b46\"}"
      }
    }
  ]
}



Thank you so much! This is awesome. Can you advise how I would insert another choice condition into it? So if ColleagueType is equal to intern?

"display": "=if(([$City]=='London' || [$City]=='Manchester') && toString([$EmployeeID])!='' && toString([$BuddyPerson])!='' && ([$ColleagueType]=='Intern'), 'block', 'none')" 

See, I've added another AND (&&) condition for the display attribute. Hope this helps.. let me know

Brilliant! Thank you so much for your help
